# Difference between calling stage.width and stage.stageWidth?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

In as3 What is the **difference between calling stage.width and stage.stageWidth**

I read somewhere that if we have nothing on stage then the value of **stage.width is 0**,
but what happen when I have nothing on stage but loading contents dynamically on stage?

I have tried this and when i have loaded content dynamically on stage then i have got

```
  stage.width=value;  // where value is dynamic number
```

Can anyone explain this??
thanks.

Comment: That is a very popular question for some reason, was answered many times already (incl. here on StackOverflow).

Comment: @danii: i know its a common courtesy to accepet an answer, but when i don't get the right answer for my question then why i am going to accept that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Adobe Reference for the Stage Class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#stageWidth):

- `stage.width`

  Indicates the width of the display object, in pixels. The width is
  calculated based on the bounds of the content of the display object.

  So this property varies as you add/remove elements from the stage.
- `stage.stageWidth`

  Specifies the current width, in pixels, of the Stage.

  This property varies as you resize the Flash Player window.

Answer (score 2):

in a 800x600 swf

```
    private function init(e:Event = null):void {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        Security.allowDomain('*');
        var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
        addChild(ldr);
        trace(stage.width, stage.stageWidth);//outputs 0 800
        ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaded);
        ldr.load(new URLRequest('.../760x500.swf'));
    }

    private function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
        trace(stage.width, stage.stageWidth);//outputs 760 800
    }
```

so `stage.width` is content width and `stage.stageWidth` is your swf size

Answer (score 0):

`stage.width` is the size of the content of the stage content, so it might be anything, depending on what you have on stage (It will change if you add or remove objects), while stage.stageWidth is the size set in flash settings (the stage size can be altered externally from javascript etc. There is an event listener for that).

Answer (score 0):

- `stage.swidth`

  it will return the `width` of the content on the `stage`.
- `stage.stageWidth`
  it will give you the size of the stage. Use this if you’re trying to position elements relative to the stage